# Can I re-book my flight in Cebu Pacific over the counter or like walk in passenger?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

We are exchange students currently in Phu Quoc, Vietnam and before leaving the country we have 10 days stay in Ho Chi Minh. We would like to make our trip shorter by 7 days. If we re-book it through our agency, they will add some extra charge to the re-booking fee.

Is it possible to re-book our flight as walk in passenger or over the counter in the airport?

Answer (score 1):

In situations such as this, it's highly recommended to call up the airline and change the booking directly with them rather than through your travel agency, if the travel agency is adding an extra charge. Note that airlines often *do* charge a fee for rebooking certain classes of tickets, in addition to the difference in fare.

Your itinerary from the travel agent should have an airline booking reference or PNR. If not, ask your travel agent to provide you with the booking reference (not the same as e-ticket / ticket number). Call up the airline and discuss rescheduling the flight with them.

You *can* try to do this walk-in, but the fare difference between your advance booking and *a flight on the same day* is likely to be quite high, and you may not get a seat on the flight anyway, so it's advisable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the agent already booked our flight on February 28 2014 we just have to shortened are stay in HCM City like on February 20 2014, can we just re-book our flight on the day of our target departure?

Comment: @elrikco It's better to make those arrangements sooner rather than later. If nothing else, there may no longer be seats available if you wait until your target departure date.